# Flutter build failed with an exception ( Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest')

Tags: android, flutter, exception, build

I upgraded flutter to the latest version, made a new flutter project using vscode and copied the required files and modifications. Then when I try to run my code on an emulator I get the following:

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
> lib\main.dart:1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
>
> > com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> > F:\Muaz\Programming\Flutter\earn_finance_gold_currency\build\integration_test\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
> > (The system cannot find the file specified)

I think Integration_test is new as I have not seen it before. Can I remove it? Any other known fixes? Thanks.

Comment: Is there `android` folder in your project root folder ?

Comment: yes of-course there is

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade version android.

android/build.gradle

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties